# get Base 64 JPEG image file size

Tags: php, laravel, base64

I have code to get the filesize of a base64 image after uploading it, the code works just fine with `.png` images only increasing the file size by roughly 33% as expected. But with jpeg images, the file size goes from 100kb to 1.1mb after uploading.

Here is my code

**Code**

```
public static function create(Request $request)
{
    $image64 = $request->input('image');

    $data = explode(',', $image64);
    $decoded_64 = base64_decode($data[1]);
    $base64_size = strlen(base64_decode($data[1]));

    return $base64_size;
}
```

As I said with .png files this returns the size correctly however with jpeg images it increases the size by 1000%. The size persists after uploading to the server and then downloading again.

Comment: Have you tried opening the resulting JPEG to verify whether it's corrupted? How does size compare to the original JPEG file?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The file opens just fine + the width x height are identical

Comment: Is file size identical too?

Comment: No its literally 1000% bigger, it goes from 0.1mb to 1.1mb

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you were talking about the size increase when converting from binary to base64. Whatever, I don't see anything intrinsically wrong in your code and I cannot reproduce on my side. You'll need to inspect all variables across the flow to determine the exact spot where things go bad. Specially, how can a JPEG grow and still be valid? What's the file padded with?

Comment: no worries, ill get some more tests done and get back to you, so far theres still no reason for it to be increased in size, ive checked the size of the abse64 string on the JS side of things and its still a larger file size